# How do I include silent mutations in an oncoplot using maftools?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have annotated files from annvar and I changed them into MAF by using
`annovarToMaf` from [‘maftools’](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/maftools.html). Then I used `read.maf` to read them into R and then I used `merge_mafs` to integrate them together inside the last file.

I had several data frames but it separated the synonymous mutations (`maf.silent`) from the non-synonymous mutations, and I want to create an oncoplot using the `oncoplot` function for both synonymous mutations from the non-synonymous mutations.

But once I use this command I don't know how to integrate both data frames inside of the MAF file.

How can I create the oncoplot using `oncoplot` for both synonymous mutations and non-synonymous mutations?

Comment: I have tried this, not work, the LOW impact SNP still missing
df.maf <- read.maf(maf = df, vc_nonSyn = c("Frame_Shift_Del","Missense_Mutation","Nonstop_Mutation","Silent","Splice_Region")) the reason I want to include silent SNPs is that I want to plot tumor mutation signature per sample. however, I got error due to the few number of SNPs for some samples.

Answer (score 2):

This is late but I am putting it here for future reference. You can use the `vc_nonsyn` argument in the `read.maf` function to manually list the variant classifications you want to plot later. It will look like this:

```
df.maf <- read.maf(maf = df, vc_nonSyn = c("Frame_Shift_Del","Missense_Mutation","Nonstop_Mutation","Silent","Splice_Region"))
```